# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError `GOMP_4.0' Travis CI Using Java OpenCV library

Tags: java, opencv, gradle, travis-ci

I'm building my project which is using org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets version of opencv. I'm using gradle for dependency management/building/testing ect...
The build and the tests work fine on my local machine but running on travis I get the following error:

```
Caused by:
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/javacpp28510966720824/libjniopencv_core.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by /tmp/javacpp28510966720824/libopencv_core.so.3.0)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1822)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1083)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:539)
        ... 10 more
```

I have modified the travis.yml so that I can see if the files actually exist.

```bash
$ ls -l /usr/lib/*/libgomp.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Apr 15  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 -> libgomp.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55888 Apr 15  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
$ dpkg -l | grep libgomp1
ii  libgomp1                            4.6.3-1ubuntu5                                      GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library
```

On my local (OSX) and another devs machine (Linux) everything just worked. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

This is the project experiencing the problem:
https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP

Specifically this PR: https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP/pull/7

Issue regarding this problem: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So come to find out the problem was that `GOMP_4.0` is only available for gcc 4.8 and higher. The VM that Travis runs on is [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server Edition 64 bit](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/) which has gcc 4.6. gcc 4.6 has `GOMP_3.0`. Basically you need to update gcc.

In travis the best way to do this (without using sudo) is to use their apt plugin.
Just add this to your .travis.yml

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - gcc-4.8
      - g++-4.8
```

Or if you are just on an Ubuntu system and having this problem:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
```

Answer (score 0):

For maven test goal you can use maven-surefire-plugin with parameter Djava.library.path or maven-dependency-plugin with unpacking your libs.
I faced a similar problem.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <property>
                <name>TESSDATA_PREFIX</name>
                <value>${tessdata.directory}</value>
            </property>
        </systemProperties>
        <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${native.library.directory} -Djni.library.path=${native.library.directory}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I'm using gradle not maven. I'll have a look if there is a similar solution.

Comment: yes, right, builder can't find .so librares for linux or .dll for windows by "java.library.path'

Comment: Also, what do I set the native.library.directory path too?
I have no idea where gradle puts dependencies it has downloaded.

Comment: try to look at log files on Travis CI if it possible

Comment: oh, I've found same issue with gradle. https://github.com/pbl2014/Detector/commits/master?page=3 since add CvTest.java you can see all way )

Comment: As I understand, just add  before_install:
  - "sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev"

Comment: That didn't resolve it either.
The other problem is that using `sudo` makes travis run on old architecture.
Regardless it didn't resolve the issue.
Have a look at my updated OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88637/discussion-between-jonathan-leitschuh-and-oleksandr-loushkin).